# iOS - Control UISlider using UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I currently have a UISlider in my view and I'm trying to change the UISlider value when the user pinch in and out using UIPinchGestureRecognizer. The UISlider name is `pinchSlider` and the UIPinchGestureRecognizer method name is `pinchGesture:`. In my code now I change the value of `pinchSlider` to the `pinchRecognizer.scale` and this keeps resetting the `pinchSlider` value every time. Here's my code:

```
func pinchGesture(pinchRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
      if pinchRecognizer.state == .Changed {
          pinchSlider.setValue(Float(pinchRecognizer.scale), animated: true)
      }
}
```

So  what would be the best method to change the value of `pinchSlider` when the user pinch?

Thanks!

Comment: That code should work. What do you mean it keeps resetting the slider value every time? It changes more often than you want it to? It resets to it's starting value? What is the range of your slider, and what is the range of the scale you get from the pinch gesture recognizer? You probably have to adjust the reading of the pinch recognizer so it is in the correct range for the slider.

Comment: @DuncanC It sets the slider value to 1.0 every time I pinch. Yes I think I have to adjust the reading of the gesture recognizer but I'm not sure how can I do that

Comment: What is the range of the pinch gesture recognizer? What is the range of the slider? Write an equation that translates from the pinch range to the slider range. Should be pretty simple.